# mysql gui tools 64-bit rpm

Tags: mysql, 64-bit, client

Are there any 64-bit version RPMs of MySQL GUI Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or any GUI Tool built on Java would work. You just need 64-bit JRE.

**[Edited]**

[MySql Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/index.html) and [MySql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/index.html) both are developed based on x86-64 architecture.